# can't login in public IP AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

When I ssh to the AWS Instance **ssh ubuntu@public-ip** this **takes me to the private ip prompt ubuntu@private-ip**. I believe the **Network Address Translator** is coming in the way and translating the public IP to the private IP.

What I want, is to be able to ssh to the public IP ( the **prompt should show ubuntu@public IP** instead of ubuntu@private IP ).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will always go to the **Private IP address**. This is correct behaviour.

The Internet Gateway performs a **reverse NAT**, accepting traffic on the public IP address and sending it to the instance's private IP address. In fact, the instance does not even know its public IP address because all traffic is received on the private IP address. (It can lookup its public IP address via Instance Metadata, if required.)

This method has the benefit that instances can change Public IP addresses without requiring reconfiguration nor reboot. An Elastic IP address can be reassigned to another instance and traffic will immediately flow to the new instance without the old or new instances requiring any configuration change.

So, from the Internet you will connect to the instance via Public IP address, but the machine receives the traffic on its Private IP address.

Comment: Actually before I was able to log in directly to the public IP.

Could you please tell me how could i access the files. I also installed a couple of other things but here it is almost blank.

Comment: @AnkitChauhan -- If you have another question, please start a new Question and provide details rather than asking in a comment.